# PageLoad in Animate Callback with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I would like to do page load event when animation is ended. That's may be pretty simple.
Here is my Jquery code

```
$('#reload span').click(function () {
   $('#dl-area').animate('blink', 'fast', null, function () {
       location.reload();
   });
});
```

It's not working.

Comment: What is `'blink'`? `.animate()` doesn't take a string and that's not a jQuery UI effect.

Comment: @Nick I would like to do blink effect for that element. Help me pls.I don't know how to make blink effect.

Comment: something like pulsate?  http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: @Nick Correct ! The one I want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the jQuery UI pulsate effect (based on comment above), make sure you're using jQuery UI ([or just the subset you want](http://jqueryui.com/download)) and use [`.effect()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/) instead of [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) (which doesn't take a string as it's first argument), like this:

```
$('#reload span').click(function() {
   $('#dl-area').effect('pulsate', 'fast', function() {
       location.reload(true);
   });
});
```